# Сохранить пароль в браузере при отправке формы через JS/jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Друзья, подскажите, как предлагать клиенту сохранить в браузере данные для авторизации при отправке формы посредством JS/jQuery ajax? Когда стандартным способом отправляешь форму, то всплывает окошко в браузере с предложением сохранить данные, а если ev.preventDefault(), то ничего не происходит. Как решить?

HTML

```
<form id="form_2">

<input type="email" id="email" name="email">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"> 
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Войти">

</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form_2').on('submit', function (ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        // Дальнейшие действа
    });
});
```

Comment: други мои вы где

Answer (score 0):

Было найдено следующее костыльное решение:

HTML

```
<iframe src="blank.html" id="loginTarget" name="loginTarget" style="display:none"></iframe>
<form id="form-2" action="blank.html" method="post" target="loginTarget">

<input type="email" id="email" name="email">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"> 
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Войти">

</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form_2').on('submit', function (ev) {

        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        // Дальнейшие действа
    });
});
```

Грубо говоря, форма теперь сначала отправляется посредством скрытого iframe на левую страничку, вызывая окно сохранения пароля, а затем присходит ajax запрос на нужный файл.